# ReactJS axios.post inside a map through array function that returns an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I try to map through an array and for each item in the array is a parameter value for a post request. So Im looking for an finalArray with the post request response return value, and need to use the finalArray somewhere else.

```
const finalArray = paramArray.map(paramKey => {
  axios.post(URL, {
    filters: [
      {
        field: "key", 
        values: [paramKey.key]
      }
    ]
  }).then(res => {
      //res.data.itemName
    });

  return {
    key: paramKey.key,
    text: //res.data.itemName,
    value: paramKey.value
  }
});
```

so Im not sure how to pass the `res.data.itemName` outside of the function in `.then`. I tried declaring a variable before axios such as `let name = "";`, and inside `.then` I have `name = res.data.itemName`, then I pass the name to text as `text: name`, but this will give me all empty string. I also tried putting the return inside `.then`, this way the `finalArray` gives me undefined values.

Is there any way to pass the `res.data.itemName` as the value of `text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
async function() {
  const promises = paramArray.map(paramKey => axios.post(URL, {
      filters: [
        {
          field: "key", 
          values: [paramKey.key]
        }
      ]
    })
  );

  const values = await Promise.all(promises)
  const finalArray = paramArray.map((paramKey, index) => {
    return {
      key: paramKey.key,
      text: values[index].data.itemName,
      value: paramKey.value
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: But this way can I use finalArray outside of this Promise.all?

Comment: You can use await.

Comment: i updated the answer using await. by doing so, you can use finalArray.

Comment: Thanks I had to rearrange my code for a little bit to make it work, but this helped a lot!